# Table cut off vertically in 2 column paper

Tags: tables

I have a problem in table format as in the following snipping, part of the table is missing 
[image]

The code that used to create the table is the following

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
   Brand & DeepLearning\_WordEmb\_LSTM & Google NLP & WordNetLexicon & Amazon Ratings  \\ \hline
 Apple & 0.52123 & 0.58509 & 0.53234 & 0.59240 \\ \hline
 Huawei & 0.57782 & 0.50757 & 0.53302 & 0.76220 \\ \hline
 Samsung & 0.56242 & 0.58984 & 0.54255 & 0.68910 \\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
\caption{Sentiment Approach Comparisons per Brand}
\label{senti_approach}
\end{table}
```

The type of documents is `\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}`

Comment: could you please tell me the exact statement and editions?! Thanks

Comment: Please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 3):

With two column format some compromises are necessary.

In your table the headers are too long to fit the column, so I suggest to use symbolic references.

```latex
\documentclass[sigconf,twocolumn]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2] % filler text

\begin{table}[!htp]
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let TeX do the calculations
\sisetup{group-digits=false} % no space between digits

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l % brand
  *{4}{S[table-format=1.5]}
}
\toprule
Brand & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} \\
\midrule
Apple   & 0.52123 & 0.58509 & 0.53234 & 0.59240 \\
Huawei  & 0.57782 & 0.50757 & 0.53302 & 0.76220 \\
Samsung & 0.56242 & 0.58984 & 0.54255 & 0.68910 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\medskip

(1) DeepLearningWordEmb\_LSTM \\
(2) Google NLP \\
(3) WordNetLexicon \\
(4) Amazon Ratings

\medskip

\caption{Sentiment Approach Comparisons per Brand}
\label{senti_approach}
\end{table}

\lipsum[3-13] % more filler text

\end{document}
```

[image]

The vertical spacing is wrong because the `acmart` class expects *top* caption for tables. The same code as before, with the table in the following format will have correct vertical spaces.

```latex
\begin{table}[!htp]
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let TeX do the calculations
\sisetup{group-digits=false} % no space between digits

\caption{Sentiment Approach Comparisons per Brand}
\label{senti_approach}

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l % brand
  *{4}{S[table-format=1.5]}
}
\toprule
Brand & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} \\
\midrule
Apple   & 0.52123 & 0.58509 & 0.53234 & 0.59240 \\
Huawei  & 0.57782 & 0.50757 & 0.53302 & 0.76220 \\
Samsung & 0.56242 & 0.58984 & 0.54255 & 0.68910 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\medskip

(1) DeepLearningWordEmb\_LSTM \\
(2) Google NLP \\
(3) WordNetLexicon \\
(4) Amazon Ratings

\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, the `tabular` environment that's embedded in the `table` environment is much too wide to fit inside a single text column. The "culprits" are the text strings in the headers of the four data columns and, in particular, the long string `DeepLearning\_WordEmb\_LSTM`.

I can think of two remedies:

- Replace `\begin{table}[h]` and `\end{table}` with `\begin{table*}` and `\end{table*}`, respectively. With this change, LaTeX will typeset the table across both columns at the top of a page.
- Introduce line breaks in the header cells, as needed, and employ a `tabularx` environment to assure that the material's overall width is `\columnwidth`.

  - In the following example, I chose to assign a greater width to the first data column to the other three, in order to limit all header cells to just two rows. Note also that `1.333+3*0.899=4`; 4 is also the number of columns of type `X`. Why 0.889 and 1.333?, you might ask. No particular reason, except that 1.333 is 50% greater than 0.889.
  - I had to make some guesses as to what the acceptable line-break points might be in two of the four headers. You may, or may not, agree with these guesses.
  - I've also given the table a much more open "look" by omitting all vertical lines and using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigconf,twocolumn]{acmart}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
  >{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
    \hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2] % filler text

\begin{table}[h]
\urlstyle{same}
%\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} l C{1.333} *{3}{C{0.889}} @{}}
\toprule
   Brand & DeepLearning\-WordEmb\_LSTM & Google NLP & WordNet\-Lexicon & Amazon Ratings  \\ 
\midrule
 Apple & 0.52123 & 0.58509 & 0.53234 & 0.59240 \\ %\hline
 Huawei & 0.57782 & 0.50757 & 0.53302 & 0.76220 \\ %\hline
 Samsung & 0.56242 & 0.58984 & 0.54255 & 0.68910 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Sentiment Approach Comparisons per Brand}
\label{senti_approach}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2] % more filler text
\end{document}
```